# How to sort a hash by value in descending order and output a hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

```
output.sort_by {|k, v| v}.reverse
```

and for keys

```
h = {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}
=> {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}

Hash[h.sort]
```

Right now I have these two. But I'm trying to sort hash in descending order by value so that it will return

```
=> {"d"=>4, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "a"=>1 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
let me post the whole code.

```
def count_words(str)
  output = Hash.new(0)
  sentence = str.gsub(/,/, "").gsub(/'/,"").gsub(/-/, "").downcase
  words = sentence.split()
  words.each do |item|
    output[item] += 1 
  end
  puts Hash[output.sort_by{ |_, v| -v }]
  return Hash[output.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
end
```

Comment: Remember that hashes do not have an order previous to Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try:

```
Hash[h.sort.reverse]
```

This should return what you want.

**Edit:**

To do it by value:

```
Hash[h.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
```

Comment: but that sort the key thought, i'm trying to sort the value

Comment: hmmm....i thought that's the way too. How come I see unless1sunday1or1on2of2due1the5is1day2saturday1rent1falls1first2month2a1.. All the keys and values stuck together in the irb.

Comment: It comes out perfectly fine for me. Are you using something other than this test hash?

Comment: nope... well, if that's the way to sort it. then it probably something else making it output the wrong hash. I'll double check. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "How come I see unless1sunday1or1on2of2due1the5is1day2saturday1rent1falls1first2month2a1", what version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
Hash[h.sort_by{ |_, v| -v }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here are 2 other solutions, which are close, but found it more obvious when reading :

```
h = {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "d"=>4}

hash.sort_by(&:last).reverse # => [["d", 4], ["c", 3], ["b", 2], ["a", 1]]

hash.sort { |a,b| b.last <=> a.last }
```

Call to_h if you really need a hash instead of an array of arrays :

```
hash.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h # => {"d"=>4, "c"=>3, "b"=>2, "a"=>1}

hash.sort { |a,b| b.last <=> a.last }.to_h
```